# Trying to setup a PHP daemon using System_Daemon and I'm having issues getting it to run

Tags: php, ubuntu, daemon

I get the following error when trying to start a daemon using Ubuntu 10.04 and the PHP5:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'usr/lib/php5/20060613/pcntl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613/pcntl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Does System_Daemon try to call pcntl? If so, why is it looking for the file where it does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `System_Daemon` uses the `pcntl_fork` function to spawn its child processes. I'd guess you don't have pcntl [installed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php). If you do, you could create a symlink to the `pcntl.so` file at that path so PHP can find it.

Comment: Isn't pcntl installed by default in PHP5?

Comment: The installation instructions I linked state "Process Control support in PHP is not enabled by default."

Comment: Strange because pcntl.ini exists, but the .so file does not.  I guess I need to do some research on how to recompile PHP with pcntl.